# How do I enable 2-sided printing with a Xerox DocuPrint laser printer?

Tags: printing, printer

After installing the drivers for my DocuPrint C2255 printer, it just will not allow me to select double-sided printing.

- The PCL driver does not even display "2 sided" as an option in the drop-down
- The PostScript driver displays the option, but when selected gives this slightly confusing error...

  [image]

It seems to think that the duplex unit is not installed.  What do I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally found that you had to manually tell the driver about the presence of the duplex unit.  This is done through Control Panel > Printers & Devices > right-click your printer > Printer Properties.

**For the standard PCL Driver...**

[image: DocuPrint C2255 Duplex Enabled]

**For the PS Driver...**

[image: DocuPrint C2255 Duplex Enabled PS Driver]

Comment: Hi Simon. Can you accept your own answer? That way it will not get bumped to the front page (Which happens now and then with questions with no accepted answers).